# Distinction between definiteness and specificity

Tags: terminology, linguistic-typology, definiteness

May I have an example of a language which separately marks definiteness and specificity (or indefiniteness and non-specificity), and also a principled way for deciding which of the two sets of terms is appropriate in description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a paper about these topics, among others, many years ago, which was translated into French before being published (in *Langages* 48, 1976).

Here's the [original English MS](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/someproblemsofreference.pdf) and the [French translation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/quelquesproblemes.pdf) of "Quelques Problèmes de Référence", aka "Some Problems of Reference".

### The OP has added this material summarized from the cited paper:

NP's in English which are marked as indefinite can be ambiguous for specificity. The example given in the paper is that the phrase "I'm looking for a policeman" is ambiguous between two readings:

1. I'm looking for *a policeman*, but I can't find him. (specific)
2. I'm looking for *a policeman*, but I can't find one. (non-specific)

Specific indefinites are associated with specific instantiations of a referring phrase (in addition to lexical and definitional information), while non-specific indefinites are only associated with lexical or definitional information associated with referring phrase.

Comment: I like reading something in French every now and then ;-) thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to have a summary (in the context of the question), for the sake of the readers? Like if there are example languages, or how to distinguish the two sets of terms?

Comment: In English specific and non-specific indefinite NPs are distinguished in syntax, though not morphology. E.g, _I'm looking for a policeman, but I can't find him/one; him_ is used for the specific, and _one_ for the non-specific. The paper goes into the interactions of these categories, among others.

Comment: As for some principled ways to distinguish them, and lots of examples, I'd recommend pp 71-78 of Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_, which is what's listed in the index under _Definiteness, versus Specificity_.